# Implement MyMap (Higher Order Function) in Scala

Tags: scala, fold

myMap should take two curried Function.
1) Generic List
2) Function that evaluates every element of List.

Return value of myMap is List after applying Function to every element.

```
def myMap (f: Int=>Int) ( L:List[Int]) : List[Int] = 
   {
      var xx = L
         if(L.isEmpty)  Nil
        val (head::tail) = xx
       f(head) :: myMap (f) (tail)
     }
```

It is giving me immutable warning.

Comment: def myMap (f: Int=>Int) ( L:List[Int]) : List[Int] = 
   {
     var xx = L
     if(L.isEmpty)  Nil
     val (head::tail) = xx
     f(head) :: myMap (f) (tail)
   }

Comment: 1 - There's no reason to create `xx`. Just use `L`. (Except you should avoid capitol-letter variable names.) 2 - There is no `else` clause to your `if` statement so all the code is executed whether `L` is empty or not.

Comment: 3) Homework should not be done by asking questions on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working solution

```
def myMap(f: Int => Int)(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: tail =>
      f(head) :: myMap(f)(tail)
  }
}
```

Your code (besides formating) has number of problems.

Don't use capital letters for vals

Your `var` is pointless as you never modify it, this assignment is useless anyway as you can simply use your argument.

Your if needs an else, otherways it won't magicly return that `Nil`

You can make this function generic replacing Int with generic type

```
def myMap[A](f: A => A)(list: List[A]): List[A] = {
  list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: tail =>
      f(head) :: myMap(f)(tail)
  }
}
```

To make your if else solution work you can do this:

```
def myMap[A](f: A => A)(list: List[A]): List[A] = {
  if (list.isEmpty) {
    Nil
  } else {
    val (head :: tail) = list
    f(head) :: myMap(f)(tail)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would work if you add the missing else block

```
def myMap (f: Int=>Int) ( L:List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
  var xx = L
  if(L.isEmpty)  Nil
  else { 
    val (head::tail) = xx
    f(head) :: myMap (f) (tail)
  }
 }
```